# Updated Linux kernel, NVIDIA driver not functioning. OS is running at lower resolution with most features unusable

Tags: 12.10, kernel

After I updated my Linux kernel this morning, my computer no longer boots up with the NVIDIA logo, and instead with an Intel one. I updated my drivers and rebooted, still had the same problem. The computer now runs at a lower resolution, and I can't see the sidebar with applications, or the context menu at the top of the screen. My computer is basically unusable with Ubuntu right now. I'm quite sure that this problem does not have to do just with the drivers.

Comment: I can be fixed, but a reinstall would be a lot simpler, if that's an option.

Comment: @DominicJordanHasford That's rather a destructive suggestion to throw around without giving a reason *why* it's easier to reinstall. In this case I completely disagree (you can fix this with two commands) but I'd like to know your reasoning.

Comment: How is that a destructive suggestion? That seems like a slight exaggeration. It was a comment to gather info, not an answer, thus I did not go deep into detail. Just as you did not go into great detail either. In my humble opinion, I believe that backing up ones data and starting a fresh install is safer/simpler than playing with the kernel and graphics drivers. Really any one who has ever tried doing so knows it is risky, and can damage your system. Like what happened to @user141673 now. Messing with the kernel and graphics drivers doesn't always work out as it should, IT can be destructive.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use untested software in the future, please read around the subject before you put your system in peril. If you had, you would have seen that [the x-swat page recommends `ppa-purge`](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates):

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

This should get you back to a state where you're running on the standard stack.

Comment: Did not solve my problem.

Comment: @user141673 What did it do? Can you edit the question to update people on the current situation?

Comment: It had no effect.